# Find general formula for this function/step on an array of integers

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose we have an array of size N and let's define a function/step as described in the following picture for an array of size 5 :-
[Example Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T4Myp.png)
Can we find a general mathematical formula for this problem so that we can find the value of any array element on ith step ?

Answer (score -1):

I will slightly modify your notation to make it easier to write: By $A_n[k]$ I refer to the $k$'th entry in the array in the $n$'th step, and the initial array I will refer to as the zero'th step.  That is to say for examples: $A_0[1]=7, A_0[2]=8,\dots, A_2[2]=68,\dots$

We recognize first that $A_n[5]=5$ for all $n$.

We then recognize that for $k\neq 5$ we have

$A_n[k]=A_{n-1}[k]+A_n[k+1]=A_{n-2}[k]+A_{n-1}[k+1]+A_n[k+1]=\dots$

$ = A_0[k]+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n A_i[k+1]$

We can now continue to work backwards to fill in the details, $A_n[4]=A_0[4]+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n A_i[5] = 10+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n5=10+5n$

$A_n[3]=A_0[3]+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n A_i[4]=9+\sum\limits_{i=1}^n 10+5i=\dots$

$\dots=9+10n+5\cdot\frac{n^2+n}{2}$

We can continue working backwards coming up with expressions for $A_n[2]$ and $A_n[1]$ by plugging in the formula for the previously found entry and using standard summation techniques for summing polynomials.  The expressions will wind up being cubic and quintic polynomials in $n$ respectively.  I will leave the remaining two for you to do, but it will help to remember that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n1=n$, that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^ni=\frac{1}{2}n(n+1)$, that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^2=\frac{1}{6}n(n+1)(2n+1)$ and that $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n i^3=\frac{1}{4}n^2(n+1)^2$

The terms for $A_n[3]$ for example will follow the pattern $9,24,44,69,99,134,174,\dots$

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This is really helpful. One more thing I want to ask is that can we find the number of occurrences of some array element to the right of A[1] in A[1] in nth step ?